# Deleting root pfifo_fast (tc) on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, traffic-shaping, tc

I'm trying to delete all qdiscs to do "fresh" configuration:

```
% tc qdisc del dev enp0s25 root
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

But it's there:

```
% tc qdisc show
qdisc noqueue 0: dev lo root refcnt 2 
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev enp0s25 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
qdisc noqueue 0: dev br0 root refcnt 2
```

I have this interface added to a bridge:

```
% brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.001999bf72bb   no      enp0s25
```

Why can't I delete `pfifo_fast` from the root qdisc?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the default qdisc (there has to be one), you can change it by editing sysctl properties.
For example, if you want fq_codel instead :
In /etc/sysctl.d/88-qdisc.conf

```
net.core.default_qdisc=fq_codel
```

Then apply the configuration :

```
sysctl --system
```